# Question on the existence of a boundary between divergence and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is said that $\sum1/n^{1+\epsilon}$ will converge and $\sum1/n$ will not. There are various proofs showing that such a boundary between divergence and convergence does not, in principle, exist. This is of course evident in the above, where $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small, e.g. $0.1, 0.01, 0.001$, etc. Resultantly, this boundary can't really be cast in specific terms. However, I am wondering if it is permissible to nonetheless say that $1/n$ is the fastest decreasing divergent series. That is to say that anything decreasing faster, even by an infinitesimally small value, will converge. Can we refer to this 'boundary' not as a boundary per se, but a minimum condition, the minimum being the series $\sum S$ converges only if it decreases with greater speed than $\sum 1/n$?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is, "No." Each of $$\sum\frac{1}{n\ln(n)},\ \sum\frac{1}{n\ln(n)\ln(\ln n)}
,\ \text{etc.}$$ all diverge, each one slower than the previous. (It is plenty possible that I don't understand your question... for example, it's clear that there is no maximum at how quickly a series can grow but I think you mean to ask about how *slowly* a series grows).

Comment: $1/n$ doesn't grow, it decreases.

Comment: @rage_man I think you probably mean $\sum1/n^{1+\varepsilon}$ in the beginning of your post. The statement you mention restricts the analysis to a specific class of series, so the boundary clearly exists within that class...

Comment: @Clayton my usage of 'growth' vs 'decrease' was confusing. I've made some small edits regarding language to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: @PierreCarre quite right, I thought the p = 1 was implicit. I've adjusted this in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is interesting. Actually, things are not so simple. There are many (infinite) different series *"between"* 
$$
\sum \frac{1}{n}=\infty  \quad\textrm{and}\quad  \sum \frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}<\infty
$$
(for any $\varepsilon>0$),
some convergent and some other divergent. For example:
$$
\sum \frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)}=\infty,  \quad 
\sum \frac{1}{n\cdot (\ln\,n)^{1+\varepsilon}}<\infty
$$
and
$$
\sum \frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)\cdot \ln(\ln (n))}=\infty, \quad 
\sum \frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)\cdot (\ln (\ln (n)))^{1+\varepsilon}}<\infty
$$
and so on.
The ordering of the series is 
$$
\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)}>\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)\cdot \ln(\ln (n))}>\ldots \\
\ldots > \frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)\cdot (\ln (\ln (n)))^{1+\varepsilon}}>\frac{1}{n\cdot (\ln\,n)^{1+\varepsilon}}>\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}
$$
(For each $\varepsilon>0$, $1/n^\varepsilon<1/(\ln n)^k$ for $n$ sufficiently large.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can I ask how you're qualifying speed here, such that you know $1/{n ln(n)}$ decreases faster than $1/n$? Is it simply that the value is smaller for all $n$, $n>e$?

Comment: Ok, I add integration to the answer

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, just as there's no way to zero in on the boundary from the side of convergence as there will always be a more slowly decreasing convergent series -- there's no way to go from the side of divergence as there will always be a more quickly decreasing divergent series? For example, $1/{n{\ln}n}$, which decreases faster than $1/n$ but still diverges?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Moreover, I am quite sure that you can find a single divergent series slower than any $\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)\cdot \ln(\ln (n))\ldots \ln\ln\ldots\ln\, n}$, or a convergent series slower than any $\frac{1}{n\cdot \ln(n)\cdot \ln(\ln (n))\ldots (\ln\ln\ldots\ln\, n)^{1+\varepsilon}}$